# SSRS Report Timeout inside Business Intelligence Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, business-intelligence, connection-timeout

Currently I am trying to "refresh fields" inside Business Intelligence Studio and I am getting the following error:

"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Background Information:

1. Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
2. Report is pretty complex, usually takes 30-60 seconds to complete (depending on filtered criteria entered)
3. The timeout happens around 30 seconds after inputting parameters.
4. Query Type: Text

Things I have tried:

1. Setting the "Connect Timeout" to 6 minutes on the Connection String for the Data Source.
2. Tools -> Database Tools -> Query and View Designers, increased Cancel After to 10 minutes.
3. Setting parameters to make sure it won't return data (speed up execution time)
4. SELECT TOP 0 in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Update the "Time out (in seconds):" field for the dataset that is taking a long time. Under dataset properties. Bump it up to 120 if your query tends to run a minute.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your reporting server. Go to report -> Manage -> and set the timeout to : "Do not timeout report". Same has been shown in the image :

[image]

Comment: May I know are you viewing the report through Visual Studio or through the reporting server??

Comment: Visual Studio, trying to click Refresh Fields

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some source is not responding. What happens if you open  data source -> edit > Test connection, on all your sources?